# Class with some instruction inside

Tags: python, class

I have seen that if I write this code:

```
class Test:

   print("inside class")

   def __init__(self):
       pass

Test()
```

I have this output: 'inside class'
It is strange, is a class only a function in python?
It is possible to simulate a class with a function?

Comment: That code is called as the class body is defined / evaluates

Comment: Don't forget to indent your code.. as it written now, it is simply a syntax error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, one point in which they differ is the time when their bodies are executed.

Function and method bodies are not executed on import time, but class bodies (even nested class bodies) are.

Demo script:

```
class Upper:
    print('Upper')
    class Mid:
        print('Mid')
    def method(self):
        class Low:
            print('Low')
        print('method')
```

Output:

```
$ python3
>>> import demo
Upper
Mid
```